# Return not working with Observable.toPromise() in canActivate: Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have added a route guard to check if the user is authenticated and can login to the app. Below is a code snippet that shows how I have 2 different conditions to handle if the user is authenticated or not:

```
if (this.adal.user.isAuthenticated) {
  return true;
} else {
  this.adal.acquireToken(clientId).toPromise().then((data) => {
    console.log('Refreshed the token.');
    return(true);
  }).catch ((error) => {
     console.log('No user logged in.');
     this.router.navigate(['/login']);
     return(false);
  });
}
```

The problem is when the else part of the code is called, i.e., the acquireToken() is called it returns an observable which I'm converting to a promise. Once the token is renewed, I'm returning true. But, I see a blank page when this happens, as if "return true" is never called. Not sure why this is happening, maybe the way I'm using toPromise method is not right. It would be great if somebody can give me a little hint on this.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the interface defintion](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate), CanActivate can return an Observable, Promise or boolean but not a subscription :

```
interface CanActivate {    
   canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):
     Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean 
}
```

You could change your code like this :

```
if (this.adal.user.isAuthenticated) {
  return of(true);
} else {
  this.adal.acquireToken(clientId).pipe(map(() => true))
  .catch ((error) => {
     console.log('No user logged in.');
     this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  });
}
```

Comment: just tried it, it never gets called. The acqureToken() true body never gets called and nor the error body.

Comment: Here is a demonstration based on redirecting to the right component depending on the plateform : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-50118192
I added a 2 secondes delay for a better demonstration.

Comment: Thanks! I tried doing that too, but it seems none of the router navigate method is working inside the acquireToken method.

Comment: Could you share your updated code ? A stackblitz would be better.